# optimal policy in reinforcement learning

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a doubt.
if there are two different policies $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are the optimal policy in a reinforcement learning task, will the linear combination of the two policies $\alpha \pi_1 + \beta \pi_2, \alpha + \beta = 1$ be the optimal policy.

here I give a simple demo.

In a task, there are three states $S_0, S_1, S_2$, the action space contains two actiones
$a_1, a_2$, $s_1, s_2$ are both terminate stae. an agent will start from $s_0$, it can choose
$a_1$, then it will arrive $s_1$， and recive a reward of +1, it can also choose
$a_2$, then it will arrive $s_2$, and  recive a reward of +1.

In this simple demo task, we can first derive two different optimal policy $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$.
where $\pi_1(a_1|s_0) = 1$, $\pi_2(a_1 | s_1) = 1$. the combination of $\pi_1$ and$\pi_2$ is
$\pi: \pi(a_1|s_0) = \alpha, \pi(a_2|s_0) = \beta$. $\pi$ is the optimal policy, too. Beacuse
any policy in this task is a optimal policy.

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged on SE sites (although, personally, I don't think it's a problem). Anyway, this question was also asked [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/24686/2444), and it already has an answer there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already an answer here https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24686/given-two-optimal-policies-is-an-affine-combination-of-them-also-optimal.